# Autotools new cpu support

Tags: embedded-linux, autotools, autoconf

What would be right way to add arm64 bit support for an autools based package.

I am trying to cross compile [libdbuscpp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dbus-cplusplus/files/dbus-c%2B%2B/0.9.0/libdbus-c%2B%2B-0.9.0.tar.gz) for arm64 bit architecture.

I see there is a file called `config.sub` that lists all supported cpu. `autoreconf -vfi` is again not updating the cpu sets.

Should I maually edit this file ?

Comment: And what's exactly wrong with that right now? Autotools should be most recent which support arm64 (or aarch64, whatever name has been chosen).

Comment: What difficulty did you actually encounter in your cross-compilation?  What arguments did you pass to `configure`?  In what way did `configure` fail?  Or did it fail at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions of libtool and automake have `config.sub` files that have aarch64 support.  You should consider updating GNU Build System tools.

Comment: Yes this helped me out. I was using autoreconf 2.63. After moving to autoreconf 2.69 this problem was resolved.